# Can´t render upload images in Magnolia CMS

Tags: image, content-management-system, render, magnolia

i have a content app in Magnolia CMS, now i need to redner a image of the class DamUploadFieldDefinition from a content app

[jcr node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmYuT.jpg)

I have tried this in my .ftl:

```
<img src = "${cmsfn.link(news.jcrPhoto)}" />
```

But only return a path of the photo and can´t render my photo

Searching i found this solution but doesn´t render:

```
<img src="${damfn.getRendition(news.jcrPhoto, "myAssetVariante").link}" />
```

I was looking in another content app named "contacts" of MAgnolia, and they make it through a model class:

```
public class NewsModel<RD extends TemplateDefinition> extends AbstractSTKTemplateModel<TemplateDefinition> {

    private Node news;

    @Inject
    public NewsModel(Node content, TemplateDefinition definition, RenderingModel<?> parent,
            STKTemplatingFunctions stkFunctions, TemplatingFunctions templatingFunctions) {
        super(content, definition, parent, stkFunctions, templatingFunctions);
        System.out.println("Entramos en el constructor");

    }

    /**
     * FIXME: should be done better (binaryHandling): SCRUM-525.
     */
    public String getPhoto() {
        System.out.println("BOB inicio en el getPhoto");
        if (news == null) {
            System.out.println("news == null");
            return null;
        }
        Property binaryData = null;
        try {
            if (news.hasNode("photo")) {
                System.out.println("Tenemos contenido");
                Node binaryNode = news.getNode("photo");
                binaryData = binaryNode.getProperty("jcr:data");
            }
        } catch (RepositoryException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        if (binaryData != null) {
            System.out.println("retornamos desde templatingFunctions");
            return templatingFunctions.link(binaryData);
        } else {
            System.out.println("retornamos null");
            return null;
        }
    }

    public ContentMap getNews() {
        System.out.println("Inicio getNews");
        ContentMap cm = templatingFunctions.asContentMap(news);
        System.out.println("ContentMap=\n"+cm);
        return cm;

    }

    public void setNews(Node news) {
        this.news = news;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() {
        System.out.println("En el execute");
        try {
            NodeIterator ni = content.getNodes();
            System.out.println("size:"+ni.getSize());
            while(ni.hasNext()){
                System.out.println(ni.toString());
                Node n = ni.nextNode();
                System.out.println(n.getIdentifier());
            }
        } catch (RepositoryException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        //String id =  PropertyUtil.getString(content, "news");
        String id = "651c7140-b681-45b4-8814-ae26bfa0ba0d";
        news = null;
        System.out.println("id="+id);
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(id)) {
            System.out.println("En el if del execute");
            try {
                news = new HTMLEscapingContentDecorator(true).wrapNode(NodeUtil.getNodeByIdentifier("news",id));
            }
            catch (RepositoryException e) {
                System.out.println("Can't get uuid: '" + id + "' of contact.");
            }
        }

        return super.execute();
    }

}
```

And my FTL is:

```
[#assign news = model.news!]
7
[#if news?has_content]
8
    [#assign hasPhoto = model.photo?has_content]
[/#if]
[#if contact?has_content]
9
    [#if hasPhoto]
10
        <dl class="media photo pos-2">
            <dt><img src="${model.photo}"/></dt>
        </dl>
    [/#if]
[/#if]
```

When i put `String id =  PropertyUtil.getString(content, "news");` ID is null so don´t pass in         `if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(id)) {`

So i hardcode putting

```
String id = "651c7140-b681-45b4-8814-ae26bfa0ba0d";
```

and run all code but id doesn´t show the img

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlADs.jpg)

Showing Google´s console i can see the image path:

```
/mgnl-prosegur-intra-webapp/01/photo
```

But even putting the src like Contacts content app with my image name, dont shows anything

```
<img src="/mgnl-prosegur-intra-webapp/demo-project/contacts/ldavinci/photo/vitruviano.jpeg" alt="">
```

Changed to should be:

```
<img src="/mgnl-prosegur-intra-webapp/demo-project/contacts/ldavinci/photo/vitruviano.jpeg" alt="">
```

But not function
Please

Comment: Are there any errors in the log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if image is in DAM (Assets app), try this:

```
<img src="${damfn.getAssetLink(news.jcrPhoto)}">
```

Comment: Sorry Tomas but not function,returns null, i´ve tried making like content app named contacts  through a model, please see above for the updated question

Comment: OK, I see now. You don't using DAM for images, but only DamUploadFieldDefinition. For easy setup I would recommend use DAM (Assets app) directly (more functions to work with images - damfn), or BasicUploadFieldDefinition. In case you need to use DamUpload... and you have your images stored in your new repository (for your new content app) (similar to contacts). You need also set URI2RepositoryMapping for this your repository (check one for contacts in config: /server/URI2RepositoryMapping/mappings/contacts)

Comment: Thank you so much Tomas, i found all the information in https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/URI+mapping#URImapping-URItorepositorymapping     For my workspace, i needed add it to /server/URI2RepositoryMapping and i don´t need model, only with    '<img src = "${cmsfn.link(news.photo)}" /> ' it works
Thank you